# align text and images inside divs side by side

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

So I've made this `ul` with a list of `li` in. In each `li`, are there some `div` with text and images in. I have a problem where my text and images aren't in a line anymore, and I can't seem to fix it.

Just to show my problem I've set `style="width: 100px;"`, because I'm trying to get something like this, even though this is on:

[image]

```css
/* Weather icon on dashboard */

.element_weather {
    min-height: 30px !important;
    min-width: 30px !important;
}

.container_weather {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.elements_weather {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.white {
    fill: #edf8ff
}

.gray {
    fill: #cecece
}

.yellow {
    fill: #fabb33
}

.blue {
    fill: #83bfff
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul id="tog_success-123" class="list-group list-group-flush rounded" style="width: 100px;">
   <li id="1" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
      <a class="text-dark" href="TestResults?blablabla" target="_blank" >
         <div class="row justify-content-between">
            <div class="col-s-6 text-justify">
               test - 12345
            </div>
            <div class="col-s-6 d-flex ml-auto mr-0">
               <div class="col-s-3 mt-1 ml-1 mr-1">
                  <img src="https://camo.githubusercontent.com/4f70df5863fcc35898abfdc8a60628bb6aabf0fea2225cb9c63d3641c48711ef/68747470733a2f2f61746c61737369616e2e67616c6c65727963646e2e76736173736574732e696f2f657874656e73696f6e732f61746c61737369616e2f61746c6173636f64652f312e342e302f313535383132333132313437352f4d6963726f736f66742e56697375616c53747564696f2e53657276696365732e49636f6e732e44656661756c74" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="14" height="14">
               </div>
               <div class="col-s-3">
                  <div id="svg_dashboard_weather" class="element_weather" title="5/5">
                     <svg id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 44.9 44.9" style="enable-background:new 0 0 44.9 44.9;" xml:space="preserve" height="25px" width="25px">
                        <g id="Sun">
                           <circle id="XMLID_61_" class="yellow" cx="22.4" cy="22.6" r="11"/>
                           <g>
                              <path id="XMLID_60_" class="yellow" d="M22.6,8.1h-0.3c-0.3,0-0.6-0.3-0.6-0.6v-7c0-0.3,0.3-0.6,0.6-0.6l0.3,0c0.3,0,0.6,0.3,0.6,0.6 v7C23.2,7.8,22.9,8.1,22.6,8.1z"/>
                              <path id="XMLID_59_" class="yellow" d="M22.6,36.8h-0.3c-0.3,0-0.6,0.3-0.6,0.6v7c0,0.3,0.3,0.6,0.6,0.6h0.3c0.3,0,0.6-0.3,0.6-0.6v-7 C23.2,37,22.9,36.8,22.6,36.8z"/>
                              <path id="XMLID_58_" class="yellow" d="M8.1,22.3v0.3c0,0.3-0.3,0.6-0.6,0.6h-7c-0.3,0-0.6-0.3-0.6-0.6l0-0.3c0-0.3,0.3-0.6,0.6-0.6h7 C7.8,21.7,8.1,21.9,8.1,22.3z"/>
                              <path id="XMLID_57_" class="yellow" d="M36.8,22.3v0.3c0,0.3,0.3,0.6,0.6,0.6h7c0.3,0,0.6-0.3,0.6-0.6v-0.3c0-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.6-0.6h-7 C37,21.7,36.8,21.9,36.8,22.3z"/>
                              <path id="XMLID_56_" class="yellow" d="M11.4,31.6l0.2,0.3c0.2,0.2,0.2,0.6-0.1,0.8l-5.3,4.5c-0.2,0.2-0.6,0.2-0.8-0.1l-0.2-0.3 c-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.6,0.1-0.8l5.3-4.5C10.9,31.4,11.2,31.4,11.4,31.6z"/>
                              <path id="XMLID_55_" class="yellow" d="M33.2,13l0.2,0.3c0.2,0.2,0.6,0.3,0.8,0.1l5.3-4.5c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.6,0.1-0.8l-0.2-0.3 c-0.2-0.2-0.6-0.3-0.8-0.1l-5.3,4.5C33,12.4,33,12.7,33.2,13z"/>
                              <path id="XMLID_54_" class="yellow" d="M11.4,13.2l0.2-0.3c0.2-0.2,0.2-0.6-0.1-0.8L6.3,7.6C6.1,7.4,5.7,7.5,5.5,7.7L5.3,7.9 C5.1,8.2,5.1,8.5,5.4,8.7l5.3,4.5C10.9,13.5,11.2,13.5,11.4,13.2z"/>
                              <path id="XMLID_53_" class="yellow" d="M33.2,31.9l0.2-0.3c0.2-0.2,0.6-0.3,0.8-0.1l5.3,4.5c0.2,0.2,0.3,0.6,0.1,0.8l-0.2,0.3 c-0.2,0.2-0.6,0.3-0.8,0.1l-5.3-4.5C33,32.5,33,32.1,33.2,31.9z"/>
                              <animate attributeType="CSS"
                                 attributeName="opacity"
                                 attributeType="XML"
                                 dur="0.5s"
                                 keyTimes="0;0.5;1"
                                 repeatCount="indefinite"
                                 values="1;0.6;1"
                                 calcMode="linear"/>
                           </g>
                        </g>
                     </svg>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**Edit**

When my li column is getting two small in width, then the icons row jumps under, and it shouldn't.

[image]

Comment: I don't get it. If you remove that `width:100px` that artificially compresses your row (so, naturally, all items can't fit in it), and you set it to, say, 200px, you get the result you expect. All items are on one line, like the little screenshot. It seems to be working, what am I missing?

Comment: What i'm trying to do is to force the icons to always be in the same line (the first) as the text, because when the text plits into two lines then the icons also jumps down with it

Comment: Well remove `flex-wrap: wrap` then. It allows overflowing items to jump to the next line.

Comment: @JeremyThille In my edit I've shown the problem, where the div jumps under the other div, which looks wired for a user to look at.

Comment: Well found out that it was because of `row`, this should be changed to `col` didn't see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your `.row` gets applied a `flex-wrap:wrap` that comes from bootstrap.css.

You can overwrite it with `flex-wrap: nowrap` :

```css
/* Weather icon on dashboard */

.element_weather {
    min-height: 30px !important;
    min-width: 30px !important;
}

.container_weather {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.elements_weather {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.white {
    fill: #edf8ff
}

.gray {
    fill: #cecece
}

.yellow {
    fill: #fabb33
}

.blue {
    fill: #83bfff
}

.row {
    border : blue dashed 1px;
    flex-wrap : nowrap!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul id="tog_success-123" class="list-group list-group-flush rounded" style="width: 100px;">
   <li id="1" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
      <a class="text-dark" href="TestResults?blablabla" target="_blank" >
         <div class="row justify-content-between">
            <div class="col-s-6 text-justify">
               test - 12345
            </div>
            <div class="col-s-6 d-flex ml-auto mr-0">
               <div class="col-s-3 mt-1 ml-1 mr-1">
                  <img src="https://camo.githubusercontent.com/4f70df5863fcc35898abfdc8a60628bb6aabf0fea2225cb9c63d3641c48711ef/68747470733a2f2f61746c61737369616e2e67616c6c65727963646e2e76736173736574732e696f2f657874656e73696f6e732f61746c61737369616e2f61746c6173636f64652f312e342e302f313535383132333132313437352f4d6963726f736f66742e56697375616c53747564696f2e53657276696365732e49636f6e732e44656661756c74" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="14" height="14">
               </div>
               <div class="col-s-3">
                  <div id="svg_dashboard_weather" class="element_weather" title="5/5">
                     <svg id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 44.9 44.9" style="enable-background:new 0 0 44.9 44.9;" xml:space="preserve" height="25px" width="25px">
                        <g id="Sun">
                           <circle id="XMLID_61_" class="yellow" cx="22.4" cy="22.6" r="11"/>
                           <g>
                              <path id="XMLID_60_" class="yellow" d="M22.6,8.1h-0.3c-0.3,0-0.6-0.3-0.6-0.6v-7c0-0.3,0.3-0.6,0.6-0.6l0.3,0c0.3,0,0.6,0.3,0.6,0.6 v7C23.2,7.8,22.9,8.1,22.6,8.1z"/>
                              <path id="XMLID_59_" class="yellow" d="M22.6,36.8h-0.3c-0.3,0-0.6,0.3-0.6,0.6v7c0,0.3,0.3,0.6,0.6,0.6h0.3c0.3,0,0.6-0.3,0.6-0.6v-7 C23.2,37,22.9,36.8,22.6,36.8z"/>
                              <path id="XMLID_58_" class="yellow" d="M8.1,22.3v0.3c0,0.3-0.3,0.6-0.6,0.6h-7c-0.3,0-0.6-0.3-0.6-0.6l0-0.3c0-0.3,0.3-0.6,0.6-0.6h7 C7.8,21.7,8.1,21.9,8.1,22.3z"/>
                              <path id="XMLID_57_" class="yellow" d="M36.8,22.3v0.3c0,0.3,0.3,0.6,0.6,0.6h7c0.3,0,0.6-0.3,0.6-0.6v-0.3c0-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.6-0.6h-7 C37,21.7,36.8,21.9,36.8,22.3z"/>
                              <path id="XMLID_56_" class="yellow" d="M11.4,31.6l0.2,0.3c0.2,0.2,0.2,0.6-0.1,0.8l-5.3,4.5c-0.2,0.2-0.6,0.2-0.8-0.1l-0.2-0.3 c-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.6,0.1-0.8l5.3-4.5C10.9,31.4,11.2,31.4,11.4,31.6z"/>
                              <path id="XMLID_55_" class="yellow" d="M33.2,13l0.2,0.3c0.2,0.2,0.6,0.3,0.8,0.1l5.3-4.5c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.6,0.1-0.8l-0.2-0.3 c-0.2-0.2-0.6-0.3-0.8-0.1l-5.3,4.5C33,12.4,33,12.7,33.2,13z"/>
                              <path id="XMLID_54_" class="yellow" d="M11.4,13.2l0.2-0.3c0.2-0.2,0.2-0.6-0.1-0.8L6.3,7.6C6.1,7.4,5.7,7.5,5.5,7.7L5.3,7.9 C5.1,8.2,5.1,8.5,5.4,8.7l5.3,4.5C10.9,13.5,11.2,13.5,11.4,13.2z"/>
                              <path id="XMLID_53_" class="yellow" d="M33.2,31.9l0.2-0.3c0.2-0.2,0.6-0.3,0.8-0.1l5.3,4.5c0.2,0.2,0.3,0.6,0.1,0.8l-0.2,0.3 c-0.2,0.2-0.6,0.3-0.8,0.1l-5.3-4.5C33,32.5,33,32.1,33.2,31.9z"/>
                              <animate attributeType="CSS"
                                 attributeName="opacity"
                                 attributeType="XML"
                                 dur="0.5s"
                                 keyTimes="0;0.5;1"
                                 repeatCount="indefinite"
                                 values="1;0.6;1"
                                 calcMode="linear"/>
                           </g>
                        </g>
                     </svg>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your solution was better, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`row` changed to `col`, and `d-flex` added

```css
/* Weather icon on dashboard */

.element_weather {
    min-height: 30px !important;
    min-width: 30px !important;
}

.container_weather {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.elements_weather {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.white {
    fill: #edf8ff
}

.gray {
    fill: #cecece
}

.yellow {
    fill: #fabb33
}

.blue {
    fill: #83bfff
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul id="tog_success-123" class="list-group list-group-flush rounded" style="width: 100px;">
   <li id="1" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
      <a class="text-dark" href="TestResults?blablabla" target="_blank" >
         <div class="col d-flex justify-content-between">
            <div class="col-s-6 text-justify">
               test - 12345
            </div>
            <div class="col-s-6 d-flex ml-auto mr-0">
               <div class="col-s-3 mt-1 ml-1 mr-1">
                  <img src="https://camo.githubusercontent.com/4f70df5863fcc35898abfdc8a60628bb6aabf0fea2225cb9c63d3641c48711ef/68747470733a2f2f61746c61737369616e2e67616c6c65727963646e2e76736173736574732e696f2f657874656e73696f6e732f61746c61737369616e2f61746c6173636f64652f312e342e302f313535383132333132313437352f4d6963726f736f66742e56697375616c53747564696f2e53657276696365732e49636f6e732e44656661756c74" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="14" height="14">
               </div>
               <div class="col-s-3">
                  <div id="svg_dashboard_weather" class="element_weather" title="5/5">
                     <svg id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 44.9 44.9" style="enable-background:new 0 0 44.9 44.9;" xml:space="preserve" height="25px" width="25px">
                        <g id="Sun">
                           <circle id="XMLID_61_" class="yellow" cx="22.4" cy="22.6" r="11"/>
                           <g>
                              <path id="XMLID_60_" class="yellow" d="M22.6,8.1h-0.3c-0.3,0-0.6-0.3-0.6-0.6v-7c0-0.3,0.3-0.6,0.6-0.6l0.3,0c0.3,0,0.6,0.3,0.6,0.6 v7C23.2,7.8,22.9,8.1,22.6,8.1z"/>
                              <path id="XMLID_59_" class="yellow" d="M22.6,36.8h-0.3c-0.3,0-0.6,0.3-0.6,0.6v7c0,0.3,0.3,0.6,0.6,0.6h0.3c0.3,0,0.6-0.3,0.6-0.6v-7 C23.2,37,22.9,36.8,22.6,36.8z"/>
                              <path id="XMLID_58_" class="yellow" d="M8.1,22.3v0.3c0,0.3-0.3,0.6-0.6,0.6h-7c-0.3,0-0.6-0.3-0.6-0.6l0-0.3c0-0.3,0.3-0.6,0.6-0.6h7 C7.8,21.7,8.1,21.9,8.1,22.3z"/>
                              <path id="XMLID_57_" class="yellow" d="M36.8,22.3v0.3c0,0.3,0.3,0.6,0.6,0.6h7c0.3,0,0.6-0.3,0.6-0.6v-0.3c0-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.6-0.6h-7 C37,21.7,36.8,21.9,36.8,22.3z"/>
                              <path id="XMLID_56_" class="yellow" d="M11.4,31.6l0.2,0.3c0.2,0.2,0.2,0.6-0.1,0.8l-5.3,4.5c-0.2,0.2-0.6,0.2-0.8-0.1l-0.2-0.3 c-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.6,0.1-0.8l5.3-4.5C10.9,31.4,11.2,31.4,11.4,31.6z"/>
                              <path id="XMLID_55_" class="yellow" d="M33.2,13l0.2,0.3c0.2,0.2,0.6,0.3,0.8,0.1l5.3-4.5c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.6,0.1-0.8l-0.2-0.3 c-0.2-0.2-0.6-0.3-0.8-0.1l-5.3,4.5C33,12.4,33,12.7,33.2,13z"/>
                              <path id="XMLID_54_" class="yellow" d="M11.4,13.2l0.2-0.3c0.2-0.2,0.2-0.6-0.1-0.8L6.3,7.6C6.1,7.4,5.7,7.5,5.5,7.7L5.3,7.9 C5.1,8.2,5.1,8.5,5.4,8.7l5.3,4.5C10.9,13.5,11.2,13.5,11.4,13.2z"/>
                              <path id="XMLID_53_" class="yellow" d="M33.2,31.9l0.2-0.3c0.2-0.2,0.6-0.3,0.8-0.1l5.3,4.5c0.2,0.2,0.3,0.6,0.1,0.8l-0.2,0.3 c-0.2,0.2-0.6,0.3-0.8,0.1l-5.3-4.5C33,32.5,33,32.1,33.2,31.9z"/>
                              <animate attributeType="CSS"
                                 attributeName="opacity"
                                 attributeType="XML"
                                 dur="0.5s"
                                 keyTimes="0;0.5;1"
                                 repeatCount="indefinite"
                                 values="1;0.6;1"
                                 calcMode="linear"/>
                           </g>
                        </g>
                     </svg>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```